# How to keep Vim quickfix list line numbers up to date while editing the file

Tags: vim

I've been using Vim for years, but only recently did I really start using the quickfix list.

One usability issue that immediately struck me is that when I fix the first issue in the quickfix list, the line number of all the following issues are now off by a certain amount. This issue compounds very quickly if I have several errors. I almost always have to recalculate the list by running my linters again after fixing one or two issues.

Is there any way to make Vim keep the line numbers in the quickfix list up to date? When I add or remove lines above a quickfix list entry, the line number of that entry should be incremented or decremented appropriately.

Comment: Hint: Fix things starting from the **end** of the quickfix. :-)

Comment: @phd I sometimes do that, but Vim doesn't jump to the *end* of the list by default, so it's easy to forget :P Also it's uncomfortable (in my opinion)

Answer (score 2):

The quickfix *list* and the quickfix *window* are not kept up to date with the content of the buffer(s) because they reflect the output of the underlying command (grep, linter, etc.) that was *used* (in the past) to generate the list.

If you absolutely want to keep the quickfix list and window up to date with the content of the buffer, you will have to:

1. write the buffer to disk,
2. run your linter again to get a new quickfix list.

I don't think it is worth the hassle because the commands you use to jump through the list are "smart" enough to handle added and removed lines just fine:

[image: qf]

Why you don't get the expected behavior is what needs investigating, here, not how to get it.

Comment: I've actually been navigating the quickfix list using [trouble.nvim](https://github.com/folke/trouble.nvim)... I didn't realize plain Vim handled the quickfix list better 

Comment: No surprise, there.